# value replacement is not happening completely in hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Below code snippet update the value based on types in hash, it is working as expected almost but still I am surprised to see that Fixnum type is not getting completely updated and I am getting below output.

OUTPUT:

```
{ :vad_val      => "test", 
  :enabled      => nil, 
  :reg_id       => nil, 
  :buffer_value => 54, 
  :direct       => "test", 
  :direct_val   => "test", 
  :decision     => "test", 
  :number       => 54, 
  :connections  => nil, 
  :threads      => 54, 
  :updates      => nil, 
  :severity     => 54, 
  :levelval     => 54, 
  :facility     => 54, 
  :depend       => "test"
}
```

it is clear from raw_data that reg_id and connections are Fixnum so 54 is expected but still it is being replaced by nil which needs to be set when class is TrueClass. It is very minor thing but being a newbie I am not able to figure out.

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby
    require 'json'

raw_data = '{"method_name":"My function","success":true,"payload":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Elu","Properties":{"TVset":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::VirtualArea","Properties":{"vad_val":{"Type":"String","Mutable":false,"Value":"0001"},"enabled":{"Type":"TrueClass","Mutable":false,"Value":true}},"Children":{"Music":{"Type":"SM::Mod::Base","Properties":{"reg_id":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":null},"buffer_value":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":10},"special_handling_table":{"Type":"SM::Mod::SpecialHandlingTable","Properties":{"behaviors_val":{"Type":"Hash","Mutable":false,"Value":{"1":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Replace","Properties":{"direct":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}},{"Type":"SM::Mod::Behavior","Properties":{"direct_val":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"2":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::ReplaceSH","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Fromnetwork"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"3":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Fromnetwork"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"4":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::StripHeaderres","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"ToTransport"}},"Children":{}},{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"FromTransport"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"5":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::StripHeaderBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Tosnmp"}},"Children":{}},{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"FromTransport"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"6":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::ReplaceSHBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"Fromconn"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"7":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Dropfem","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"FromTransport"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"8":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::Dropfem","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"9":{"Type":"Array","Mutable":false,"Value":[{"Type":"SM::Mod::DropBehavior","Properties":{"decision":{"Type":"String","Mutable":true,"Value":"From"}},"Children":{}}],"IsActiveChange":null}},"IsActiveChange":null}},"Children":{}}},"Children":{}}}}],"IsActiveChange":null},"number":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":false,"Value":0,"IsActiveChange":false},"connections":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":null},"threads":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":4},"updates":{"Type":"TrueClass","Mutable":true,"Value":null},"severity":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":3},"levelval":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":3},"facility":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":3},"trace":{"Type":"smode::Depval::Fallback","Properties":{"enabled":{"Type":"TrueClass","Mutable":true,"Value":false},"depend":{"Type":"String","Mutable":false,"Value":""}},"Children":{}}},"Children":{}}],"error":""}'

    def create_hash(set, result = {})
      if set.class == Hash # iterate through hash
    #result.compare_by_identity

    set.each do |k, v|
          if v.class == Hash && %w(String TrueClass Fixnum).include?((v["Type"] || ''))
            result[k.to_sym] = v["Value"] # add this key's value to the output array
            if v["Value"].class==String

              result[k.to_sym]="test"
            elsif v["Value"].class==Fixnum
              result[k.to_sym]=54
            else v["Value"].class==TrueClass
              result[k.to_sym]=nil
            end
          elsif v.class == Hash || v.class == Array
            result = create_hash(v, result) # check nested arrays and hashes
          end
        end
      elsif set.class == Array
        set.each do |a|
          result = create_hash(a, result) # check elements of an array
        end
      end
      result
    end

    val = create_hash(JSON.parse(raw_data))
    p val
```

Comment: _Sidenote_: instead of comparing `var.class == Class` one would use `var.is_a? Class` and/or `Class === var`.

Comment: it is also giving me the same result which i was getting earlier.

Comment: It was a _sidenote_. The results won’t differ.

Answer (score 1):

> `{"reg_id":{"Type":"Fixnum","Mutable":true,"Value":null}`

so in If-statement

> `v["Value"].class == Fixnum`

goes **False** because `nil.class == NilClass`. So in your case you should check it not this way:

> `v["Value"].class == Fixnum`

but

```
v["Type"] == "Fixnum"
```

Comment: I tried the same and it doesn't work. I also tried to replace my entire check with similar but it doesn't work and i am getting completely unexpected result :(.

Comment: +1 vote for you :). It was my fault that i was not assigning Fixnumber  in quotes now it works as expected.

Comment: @user2997518 You just should be more carefull with this Classes thing. Strings, NilClass, Ruby chars etc. It is pretty simple article but without this knowledge you will have a lot of such situations in future.

Comment: Thanks , i will take care of this . In my response this type was considered as a string and other thing is with my implementation I was able to achieve 90 % expected result because for string and true class it was completely functional only if value is null then only it wasn't functional .

Answer (score 1):

```
        if v["Value"].class==String
          result[k.to_sym]="test"
        elsif v["Value"].class==Fixnum
          result[k.to_sym]=54
        else v["Value"].class==TrueClass
          result[k.to_sym]=nil
        end
```

In Above part of code, you are checking "value" if v.class is hash. For connections hash, connections["value"] is null and not Fixnum.

```
                "connections": {
                "Type": "Fixnum",
                "Mutable": true,
                "Value": null
            }
```

This is the reason, you are getting null against it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue what are you trying to achieve, but your approach is wrong. Let me paste the working code:

```
json = JSON.parse raw_data

def parse_hash hash
  hash.inject([]) { |memo, kv|
    next memo unless kv.last.is_a?(Enumerable)

    if kv.last.is_a? Array
      kv.last.each { |kv|
        memo += parse_hash kv
      }
    else
      if kv.last.has_key?('Type') && 
         kv.last.has_key?('Value') && 
         !kv.last['Value'].is_a?(Enumerable)
        memo << [kv.first, [kv.last['Type'], kv.last['Value']]]
      end

      memo += parse_hash kv.last
    end
    memo
  }
end
```

It sounds like we catch whatever we wanted. But wait:

```
ap parse_hash(json).map { |el|
  value = case el.last.first
          when 'Fixnum' then Integer(el.last.last || 0)
          when 'TrueClass' then !!el.last.last
          else el.last.last
          end
  [el.first.to_sym, value]
}.inject({}) { |memo, el|
  if memo.has_key?(el.first)
    memo[el.first] = [memo[el.first]] unless memo[el.first].is_a? Array
    memo[el.first] << el.last
  else
    memo[el.first] = el.last
  end
  memo
}
```

Gives us:

```
{
  :buffer_value => 10,
   :connections => 0,
      :decision => [
    [0] "Fromnetwork",
    [1] "Fromnetwork",
    [2] "ToTransport",
    [3] "FromTransport",
    [4] "Tosnmp",
    [5] "FromTransport",
    [6] "Fromconn",
    [7] "FromTransport",
    [8] "From",
    [9] "From"
  ],
        :depend => "",
        :direct => "From",
    :direct_val => "From",
       :enabled => [
    [0] true,
    [1] false
  ],
      :facility => 3,
      :levelval => 3,
        :number => 0,
        :reg_id => 0,
      :severity => 3,
       :threads => 4,
       :updates => false,
       :vad_val => "0001"
}
```

That said, the input data contained two `enabled` keys and ≈10 `decision`s. The code voluntary takes the last one, which is nonsense. So, you final result you are trying to get has no sense, since it muddles the values up.

Nevertheless, I guess I gave some hints on where to go further.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i don't want all stuff that's why this filtering is done so far and it works pretty well.

Comment: Then the code above will work for you. Please note that in your example data `reg_id` and `connections` have nil values, though they are claimed to be instances of `Fixnum`s and they appear to be interpreted as `0`s in the result.

Comment: this is reason i was not able to set the value as other fixnumbers  wherever i was setting value all ready existing value was present but fixnumber with  null value i couldn't do the same  due to nill class as mentioned by maxim. so ideally i should be set the any values (i.e. 54) with both   reg_id and connection. does your code is able to set any value to both this types apart from 0.

Comment: Of course. Look at the lines around `when 'Fixnum' then Integer(el.last.last || 0)` and change `|| 0` to `|| 54`. I hope you understand what you are doing and you are aware of the fact that as soon as input data will accidentally contain new key deeply inside a hash named, say, `connection`, everything will be ruined.

Comment: How are you executing the same , I am able to execute your first function only and not sure about ap  parse_hash as it gives error as it is not valid syntax in ruby, first function just give me list of types like below,[["vad_val", ["String", "0001"]]

Comment: `ap` in front is from `awesome_print` gem, use puts instead of `ap`.